Riemann integral with logarithm form
Let $f : [0;1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I once encountered this equality and I would like to know if it was true and if you have an idea for a proof ?
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{e^n} \dfrac{1}{n} f \left( \dfrac{\ln(i)}{n} \right) [\ln(i+1) - \ln(i)]= \int_0^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d}  t $$
I started naively with a Riemann integral and tried to change variables but without success :
$$ \int_0^1 f(t) \, \mathrm{d}  t = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n} f \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left( \dfrac{k}{n} - \dfrac{k-1}{n} \right) f \left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) =  \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{i=e}^{e^n} \left( \dfrac{\ln(i)}{n} - \dfrac{\ln(i)-1}{n} \right) f \left( \dfrac{\ln(i)}{n} \right)$$
with the change of variable $k = \ln(i)$. Can anyone help me?

If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable, then, for any sequence $\{\mathcal{P}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of tagged partitions
$$\mathcal{P}_n=\left(\left\{x^{(n)}_0,\dots,x^{(n)}_{N_n}\right\},\left\{x_1^{(n)*},\dots,x_{N_n}^{(n)*}\right\}\right)$$
of $[0,1]$ (the first part of the pair is a partition of $[0,1]$ and the second is points in each subinterval) with $\lVert\mathcal{P}_n\rVert\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, we have that
$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{N_n}f\left(x_j^{(n)*}\right)\left(x_j^{(n)}-x_{j-1}^{(n)}\right).$$
In particular, we can take the partitions
$$\mathcal{P}_n=\left(\left\{0,\frac{\ln(2)}{n},\frac{\ln(3)}{n},\dots,\frac{\ln(\lfloor e^n\rfloor)}{n},1\right\},\left\{0,\frac{\ln(2)}{n},\frac{\ln(3)}{n},\dots,\frac{\ln(\lfloor e^n\rfloor)}{n}\right\}\right)$$
to get your result (where I assume the $e^n$ as the upper bound of the sum should be interpreted as $\lfloor e^n\rfloor$).

Thanks a lot ! :)
